# Cannot find function implementation in the code

Tags: c++

In OpenVDB C++ repository, there is this condition inside [VolumeToMesh.h](https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/openvdb/blob/78b445dc8c86285539cccc512ebfbd4e96dcda26/openvdb/tools/VolumeToMesh.h#L4132):

```cpp
if (ijk[0] > origin[0] && ijk[1] > origin[1] && ijk[2] > origin[2]) {
    constructPolygons(invertSurfaceOrientation,
        flags, refFlags, offsets, ijk, *signleafPt, *idxLeafPt, mesher); // 1st function: implementation not found
} else {
    constructPolygons(invertSurfaceOrientation,
        flags, refFlags, offsets, ijk, signAcc, idxAcc, mesher); // 2nd function: implementation is found
}
```

I see the implementation for the 2nd function at [line #2512](https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/openvdb/blob/78b445dc8c86285539cccc512ebfbd4e96dcda26/openvdb/tools/VolumeToMesh.h#L2512):

```cpp
template<typename SignAccT, typename IdxAccT, typename PrimBuilder>
inline void
constructPolygons(
    bool invertSurfaceOrientation,
    Int16 flags,
    Int16 refFlags,
    const Vec3i& offsets,
    const Coord& ijk,
    const SignAccT& signAcc,
    const IdxAccT& idxAcc,
    PrimBuilder& mesher)
{
    // ...
}
```

However, the implementation for the 1st function is ***not*** found. To my surprise, in Visual Studio 2019 community edition, when I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click on 1st function, VS editor navigates to [line #2512](https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/openvdb/blob/78b445dc8c86285539cccc512ebfbd4e96dcda26/openvdb/tools/VolumeToMesh.h#L2512) which implements 2nd function!

What am I missing?

Comment: It's not one function, it's a function template. Read about them in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: @molbdnilo Sorry, you're right. Actually, the input arguments satisfy the interfaces/traits needed by template. Can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: It's not a very useful answer to anyone, including yourself, since the question does not explain why you thought the template wouldn't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @molbdnilo it is a `template` not a single function and all the input parameters passed to the `template` satisfy interfaces/traits needed by `template`.